# How to troubleshoot and resolve "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" in python

Tags: python, json, api

I have a piece of code that fetches data from the ticketmaster API using a function I've named `get_event_info`. The first revision of the code worked as desired, subsequently I modified the original function to make use of header based authentication instead of URL based. I also added a few lines to the function which were intended to validate the response status code. After making these changes the code began producing the following `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ticketmaster_only_w_headers.py", line 146, in <module>
    for event in ticket_search["_embedded"]["events"].items():
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I've read quite a bit about this type of error but I'm still unable to determine why my code is producing it in this instance. I would really appreciate an explanation on why my code is producing this error and what troubleshooting methods I should have used to uncover the source error. I'm fairly comfortable with programming but certainly no expert so the simpler the language used the better.

(Function Definition)

```
def get_event_info(search):
    if search in CACHE_DICTION:
        d = CACHE_DICTION[search]
    else:
        api_url = '{0}events/'.format(api_url_base)        
        payload = {"keyword": search, "apikey": api_token,
                   "format": "json", "dmaId": "366", "size": 200, "radius": "2"}
        response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, params=payload)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            d = json.loads(response.text)
            CACHE_DICTION[search] = d
            f = open(CACHE_FNAME, 'w')
            f.write(json.dumps(CACHE_DICTION))
            f.close()
        else:
            d = None
    return d
```

(Code snippet that triggers the error)

```
ticket_search = get_event_info("")

for event in ticket_search["_embedded"]["events"]:
    a = event["id"]
    b = event["name"]
    if "dateTime" in event["dates"]["start"]:
        c = event["dates"]["start"]["dateTime"].replace(
            "T", " ").replace("Z", "")
    else:
        c = "NONE"
    if "end" in event["dates"] and "dateTime" in event["dates"]["end"]:
        j = event["dates"]["end"]["dateTime"].replace(
            "T", " ").replace("Z", "")
    else:
        j = "NONE"
```

(Code that creates, opens, and writes to the cache used in the above code)

```
CACHE_FNAME = "ticketmaster_cache.json"                                         
try:
    cache_file = open(CACHE_FNAME, "r")                                         
    cache_contents = cache_file.read()                                          
    CACHE_DICTION = json.loads(cache_contents)                                  
    cache_file.close()                                                          
except:
    CACHE_DICTION = {}
```

---

The previous revision of the `get_event_info` function shown below which does not produce any `TypeError`:

```
def get_event_info(search, ticketmaster_key = ticketmaster_key):                                                                                
    if search in CACHE_DICTION:                                         
        d = CACHE_DICTION[search]
    else:                                                                       
        data = requests.get("https://app.ticketmaster.com/discovery/v2/events", 
            params = {"keyword": search, "apikey": ticketmaster_key,            
            "format":"json", "dmaId": "366", "size": 200, "radius": "2"})
        print(data.url)
        d = json.loads(data.text)                                       
        CACHE_DICTION[search] = d                                      
        f = open(CACHE_FNAME, 'w')                                      
        f.write(json.dumps(CACHE_DICTION))                             
        f.close()                                                       
    return d
```

Traceback & Error message I see when I run the latest revision of the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ticketmaster_only_w_headers.py", line 146, in <module>
    for event in ticket_search["_embedded"]["events"]:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a function that can explicitly return `None`, you should always check the return value first:

```py
def func(a):
    if a == 1:
        return list(range(10)) # could return a list
    else:
        return None            # or it could return None

a = 10
f = func(a)

f[1]
# raises TypeError: NoneType is not subscriptable

# check for NoneType first
if f is not None:
    print(f[1])
# otherwise, kick out different result
else:
    print('Got "None" for f!')

# Got "None" for f!
```

Your `ticket_search` is returned as `None`, but because your `for` loop is trying to do a key-lookup, it's failing, because `None` doesn't support that operation. Your logic, following from the above, should look like:

```py
if ticket_search is not None:
    for event in ticket_search["_embedded"]["events"]:
        a = event["id"]

else:
    raise TypeError
    # or do something else
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the interpreter is explicitly telling you that you are trying to evaluate something like `a[i]`, where `a` is `None` (instead of the intended type, like a list or a dict). In your case, it is either `ticket_search` itself, or `ticket_search["_embedded"]`.

In any case, if you can rerun your code at all, putting a `print(ticket_search)` under `ticket_search = get_event_info("")` should make everything clear.

Comment: Thank you! Will use this tool in the future no doubt.